# React Native mobile app posting on iOS store

Tags: ios, reactjs

When pressing on a button, the app crashes in TestFlight and it says it is calling out to a block. It does not crash in Expo.

I tried changing button to touch opacity from pressable.I tried closing popover it was in first and then linking to url. See code below:
<Pressable
onPress={() => {

```
          changePopover2(key2);
          if (appChild.type === 'BKM') {
            if (appChild.url.includes('https://')) { Linking.openURL(appChild.url) }
            else { Linking.openURL(`https://sso/${appChild.url}?access_token=${accessTokenActual}`) }
          }
          else { Linking.openURL(`https://sso/${appChild.applicationId}?access_token=${accessTokenActual}`) }

        }}
      >
```